# nlohmann json parsing key and value to a class

Tags: c++, json, c++11, c++14, nlohmann-json

I have the following data file

```json
{
   "France": {
      "capital": "paris",
      "highpoint": "20",
    },
   "Germany": {
      "size": "20",
      "population": "5000"
    }
}
```

I am using [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to parse it

I need to parse it into a country class

country.h

```cpp
class Country {
public:
  friend void to_json(json &j , const Country &c);
  friend void from_json(const json &j , Country &c); 
private:
  std::string _name; 
  std::map _detail;
```

`to_json` and `from_json`  implementation

```cpp
  to_json(json &j, const Country &c) {
    j = json{{c._name, c._detail}};

  void from_json(const json& j, Item& cat){
    auto c = j.get<std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>>();
    cat._id = c.begin()->first;
    cat._entry = c.begin()->second;
```

when i try to get the country from the json it does not work  like this

```cpp
  std::ifstream in("pretty.json");
  json j = json::parse(in);
  Country myCountry = j.get<Country>();
```

I have looked at the documentation the only i see to create the from_json is by knowing the key before hand see [doc](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#basic-usage)

`j.at("the_key_name").get_to(country._name);`

is there a way i could parse it without knowing the key ? in the from_json method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to customise to/from JSON for a vector of `Country` instead of the individual objects.

You need to parse the outer object in the JSON file and add the name to each of the objects before parsing the inner map values.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using nlohmann::json;

class Country {
public:
  friend void to_json(json& j, const std::vector<Country>& value);
  friend void from_json(const json& j, std::vector<Country>& value);
private:
  std::string _name;
  std::map<std::string, std::string> _detail;
};

void to_json(json& j, const std::vector<Country>& value)
{
  for (auto& c : value)
  {
    j[c._name] = c._detail;
  }
}

void from_json(const json& j, std::vector<Country>& value)
{
  for (auto& entry : j.items())
  {
    Country c;
    c._name = entry.key();
    c._detail = entry.value().get<std::map<std::string, std::string>>();
    value.push_back(c);
  }
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    std::stringstream in(R"({
   "France": {
      "capital": "paris",
      "highpoint": "20"
    },
   "Germany": {
      "size": "20",
      "population": "5000"
    }
})");
    json j = json::parse(in);
    std::vector<Country> myCountry = j.get<std::vector<Country>>();
    json out = myCountry;
    std::cout << out.dump(2);
  }
  catch (std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cout << ex.what() << "\n";
  }
}
```

Note that the JSON you gave in the question was not valid JSON.

Try to avoid the use of friend functions, it'd be better to add getters and setters and a constructor to the class instead.

Comment: its there are reason it would be better than using friend ?

Comment: It just allows for cleaner code, for example you might want to remove the JSON dependency from your header files, with friends you can't do this